# Tu as dit à Paul de venir? --> Oui, je le lui ai dit. Mais pourquoi?

Tags: pronoms, accord

Tu as dit à Paul de venir? --> Oui, je le lui ai dit.

Did you tell Paul to come? --> Yes, I told him to. or Yes, I told it to him?

So the direct object pronoun stands in for "de venir," but that's an infinitive w/ "de." So why isn't it "en" or just nothing?

Comment: because en is not used with dire like that. It's used with parler because parler is followed by à and then de. To use EN, you need a verb followed by à: parler **à quelqu'en de quelque chose**.  en parler à quelqu'un. To talk to someone about something. The de is what causes the EN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Le](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/le/1)* is used here because the *antecedent* is a verb. Not using it is possible and likely the most frequent usage:

> — Tu as dit à Paul **de venir** ?
>
> — Oui, je **le** lui ai dit.
>
> — Oui, je lui ai dit.

*[En](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en/1)* would have been used in reply to that question where the *antecedent* is a noun:

> — Tu as parlé à Paul de **sa venue** ?
>
> — Oui, je lui **en** ai parlé.

Comment: Très, très, clair et bien expliqué.